# How to add values to batch script variables?

Tags: batch-file

I know this may sound dumb, but I am a beginner at batch script, so I know almost nothing about it. Anyway, I want to change a variable; add 1 to it, here is my code:

```
@echo off
set num = 1
set num = %num% + 1
echo %num%
@echo on
```

Comment: easy, `set /a num+=1` and please remove the spaces before and after `=` in a standard `set` statement. i.e `set "num=1"` see `set /?` from `cmd`

Comment: yeessss, thanks! I don't understand why to remove the spaces though.

Comment: let me post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, never use spaces in a standard `set` before and after `=`. This will create a variable with a trailing space and a value with a leading space. So technically you will have `%num %` and  `1`.

To demonstrate this, simply copy everything below and paste into a `cmd` prompt.

```
@echo off
set dummy = test
set dummy
echo %dummy%
echo %dummy %
@echo on
```

similarly with:

```
@echo off
set num = 1
set num | findstr /v "NUMBER"
set /a num+=1
set num | findstr /v "NUMBER"
echo %num%
echo %num %
@echo on
```

will result in two variables, `%num %` with a value of  `1` and `%num%` with a value of `1`

The results from the above will clarify your question in the comments.

To solve your arithmetic question, simply use the `/a` switch to specify that the values are numerical and we can use arithmetic sequence operators etc. on it.

```
@echo off
set "num=1"
set /a num+=1
echo %num%
```